# Help finding a question about charged metal block expanding in volume

Tags: discussion, support

Either myself or someone else had asked a question here about how the volume of a metal block changes as it becomes positively charged (extracting electrons).

Going through my question history I couldn’t find it so I assume someone else asked it.

Using the search bar for “charged block volume”, I came up empty handed. Does anyone know where that question went?